# Issues with nodejs query. I cannot pass "+" as a query

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

When ever i pass a query B+ or A+
{{URL}}/api/help/?bloodType=B+
it gets replaced with empty space which is shown below. Any way to pass the "+" as a query. Thanks.PS: _ works perfectly fine
{"bloodType":"B "}

Comment: You need to call encodeURIComponent() on the string before you can use it as a "GET" query string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent.  The same is true for "&", "?" and other potentially troublesome meta characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` has a special meaning in url encoding, you guessed it, it means space.
You have to encode it to pass it in your url

```
'{{URL}}/api/help/?bloodType=' + encodeURIComponent('B+');
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed. Thank you very much!!:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use it directly to the URL you can also use this.

```
{URL}}/api/help/?bloodType=B%2B
```

`B%2B` is equivalent to `B+` after encoding.